# PHP & Database sign in script

Tags: php, database

i am new in php programing and i am having a lot of trouble trying to create a login php script to connect it with my mysql database (i've already create a database)

i am getting error :

content of my database is:

```
Id_Enseignant
Nom_Enseignant
Prenom_Enseignant
mail_enseignant 
Mot_de_passe 14 hh hhs   hhss
```

and this is my php script :

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\University\login.php on line 16

line 16 is this line:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1){
```

plus it showing me this next to the submit button: `"; } ?>`

```
<?php
require_once('init.php');
include_once("scripts/connect.php");
$login_error = "";
$email = "";
$password= "";

if(isset($_GET['login'])){

    $email = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
    $password = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT mail_enseignant,Nom_Enseignant,Mot_de_passe FROM enseignant WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1");


   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1){
      $row = mysql_fetch_asooc($sql);
      $_SESSION['mail_enseignant'] = $row['mail_enseignant'];
      $_SESSION['Nom_Enseignant'] = $row['Nom_Enseignant'];
      $_SESSION['Mot_de_passe'] = $row['Mot_de_passe'];


      header("Location: index.php");
      exit();

   } else {
      $login_error="invalid Information...";
   }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN" dir="ltr">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>Département Math-Info</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="wrapper row1">
  <div id="header" class="clear">
    <div class="fl_left">
      <h1><a href="index.php">Département Math-Info</a></h1>
      <p>Just Pour Vous</p>
    </div>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="login">
    <a href="login.php"><h4>Enseignant Login<h4></a>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div class="wrapper row2">
  <div id="topnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Homepage</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="style-demo.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="nouveaute.php"> Nouveauté</a></li>

      <li><a href="note-off.php">NOTE TAB</a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div  class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div class="wrapper row4">
  <div id="container" class="center">
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
   <h3>Ensiegnant Login Below</h3>
   <form action="?login" method="post" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enseingant Login</legend>


<p>Mail_Ens: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" /></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" /></p>
<p>
<?phpif (isset($login_error) && ($login_error != ""){
echo "<font color='#ff0000' style='margin-right: 10px;'".$login_error."</font>";
}?>
<input type="submit" value="Login Enseignant" name="submit_login"/></p>
      <!--  <input type="image" src="images/sign_in.gif" id="signin" alt="Sign In" />-->
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div class="wrapper row5">
  <div id="footer" class="clear">
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <div class="foot_contact">
      <h2>University Name Here</h2>
      <address>
      Address Line 1<br />
      Address Line 2<br />
      Town/City<br />
      Postcode/Zip
      </address>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Tel:</strong> xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</li>
        <li><strong>Fax:</strong> xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</li>
        <li class="last"><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="#">contact@mydomain.com</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footbox">
      <h2>Administration</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Freedom of Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Website Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press Release Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Annual Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Financial Statements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Job Vacancies</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Semester Dates</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footbox">
      <h2>Link Block 2</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Schools and Colleges</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Student Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Student Affairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Student Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Student Financial Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Student Group Directory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Student Life</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">International Students</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Global Learning</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footbox last">
      <h2>Link Block 3</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Academic Advisory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Academic Assistance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Academic Calendars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Academics Office</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Adult Learners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Alumni Chapters</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Alumni Events</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Residential Colleges</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="copyright" class="clear">
    <p class="fl_left">Copyright &copy; 2013 - All Rights Reserved - <a href="#">Domain Name</a></p>
    <p class="fl_right">Template by <a href="http://www.os-templates.com/" title="Free Website Templates">OS Templates</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am having trouble of adding the code ,every time i make submit to the code gives me error say : your topic may have code on it please provide some spaces ... even i did that i keep geting error how can  i add my script ?

Comment: space 5 times then post your code

Comment: We will need to see what you have for `$sql`. mysql_connect will return false (a boolean) if the connection fails.

Comment: good ,check my code (update) !

Comment: If your connection is working, you probably have misspelled your table name or something. Mysql was not able to find anything based on your query.

Comment: @user3566692 put `echo mysql_error();` before the `if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1){` line and see what the error says.

Comment: this is my database , and i don't think that i misspelled it :http://www14.0zz0.com/2014/04/25/02/422969049.jpg

Comment: yes thanks Himal : it says that unknow email and i changed it but i get now this error :Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_asooc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\University\login.php on line 17

Comment: @user3566692 It is mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: Great it worked ,but now how can i desplay the error and that i put it in the script :                                                  <?php if (isset($login_error) && ($login_error != "")){
    echo "<font color='#ff0000' style='margin-right: 10px;'".$login_error."</font>";
   }?>

Comment: Your strip_tags() calls are not doing anything useful.  Rather than guessing at how to properly do safe SQL queries, please learn about parametrized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters rewrite this line (you missed one parentheses):

```
<?phpif (isset($login_error) && ($login_error != ""){
```

as:

```
<?php if (isset($login_error) && ($login_error != "")) {
```

In addition, change:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_asooc($sql);
```

to:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

Also, font is deprecated...try p or h1, etc.

Comment: u mean in this code : echo "<p color='#ff0000' style='margin-right: 10px;'".$login_error."</p>"; it still did not apear in my web Site what to do thanks

Comment: You didn't close the <p> tag; rewrite as echo "<p color='#ff0000' style='margin-right: 10px;'>".$login_error."</p>";

Comment: Great my friedn it worked , can u tell me how to make it red or something ,because it's in the default color thanks

Comment: Actually, I just noticed your echo statement needs to be rewritten...can't use color = ....try this:   echo "<p style='margin-right: 10px;color: #ff0000'>".$login_error."</p>

Comment: Thanks man it worked ,but what was the problem , i even have changed the = sign to : but it didn't worked !, but with your code it worked ?

Comment: Hey My Friedn can u add me on your skype so we can talk : Serious.Gamer thanks in advance.